# Webfaction Django 1.4.1: easy_thumbnails 3.0b – "Couldn't get the thumbnail" error

Tags: python, django, thumbnails, webfaction

I use easy_thumbnails and it works fine on a development machine but in production I get errors like shown below, when I use `{% thumbnail photo.image 300x170 %}` templatetag.

Though can directly browse http://sitename.com/media/uploads/2012/09/13/microsoft1.jpeg`.
Also media set correctly and uploads are being placed at the right place, what is missing then what might be wrong?

```
File "/home/imanhodjaev/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py" in render
  823. bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/imanhodjaev/lib/python2.7/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74. return node.render(context)
File "/home/imanhodjaev/lib/python2.7/easy_thumbnails/templatetags/thumbnail.py" in render
  99. (source, e))
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /petition/microsoft-myi-hotim-kyirgyizskij-rasklad-klaviatur/update-picture
Exception Value: Couldn't get the thumbnail uploads/2012/09/13/microsoft1.jpeg: The source file does not appear to be an image
```

#### Model

`ThumbnailerImageField` from `easy_thumbnails` is used

```
class Petition(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=512, editable=False, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    petition_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    petition_picture = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path, blank=True)
```

#### Update

I did investigation from Django's management shell and `get_thumbnailer` function works fine

```
>>> thumb_url = get_thumbnailer(pet.petition_picture)
>>> thumb_url
<ThumbnailerImageFieldFile: uploads/2012/09/13/microsoft1.jpeg>
>>> thumb_url.url
'/m/uploads/2012/09/13/microsoft1.jpeg'
```

And when I call get thumbnail method it fails

```
>>> thumb_url = get_thumbnailer(pet.petition_picture).get_thumbnail(options)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/imanhodjaev/lib/python2.7/easy_thumbnails/files.py", line 380, in get_thumbnail
    thumbnail = self.generate_thumbnail(thumbnail_options)
  File "/home/imanhodjaev/lib/python2.7/easy_thumbnails/files.py", line 290, in generate_thumbnail
    "The source file does not appear to be an image")
InvalidImageFormatError: The source file does not appear to be an image
```

Comment: What the result when you try with another images?

Comment: The same result with another images

Comment: You can get more info by coding in django shell: https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails#manually-specifying-size--options

Comment: It gives `InvalidImageFormatError` though it work fine with the same image on development machine

Comment: This app depends on `PIL`. You also need to check it.

Comment: Yes PIL and other dependencies are satisfied too

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails/issues/153

Comment: I use `ThumbnailerImageField` from easy_thumbnails and libjpeg seems to work normally

Comment: All project runs inside of virtualenv

Comment: @anhtran thanks man for your time spent and efforts to help me I solved this problem and going to reply my own question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because of by default `pip install PIL` on my Webfaction instance was linked with `libjpeg` so did `pip install PIllow` and followed the article at http://community.webfaction.com/questions/7340/how-to-install-pil-with-truetype-support

Comment: Just to confirm this: all I needed was basic sorl thumbnails on Webfaction.  The key was to install Pillow instead of PIL and it worked out of the box.